# Intellij exporting WAR file with JAR library

Tags: java, grails, intellij-idea, war

I have a project in `Intellij IDEA 11.1.3` which works and is totally awesome. However, now I want to export it to a WAR-file so I went `Module->Grails->run target-><test war>` and it builds the war. Yeah, that's awesome. However when I use the application, it can't find my JAR library which it can when using it locally.

Do I need to do anything specific to use the classes within that JAR, like adding it to build path? If so, how do I do it? I really need to deploy my project to our test server.

Thanks for your sage advice and better wisdom.

**EDIT:** the library is in the lib directory and I've added the whole directory as a library to the module.

Comment: Look to $war/WEB-INF/lib . Is there your jar?

Comment: You can use third party libraries by referring to them in BuildConfig.groovy. (e.g. runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16')  This is a more elegant way to add library to Grails project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will maybe have to try that. It's very strange that it doesn't work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third-party JAR files have to be located in the "lib" directory of your grails project. Then they will be packaged by the grails war command.

Comment: They are in the lib directory, and I've added them as libraries to the project. :/

Comment: Since your answer is correct, I will accept that as an answer to my question later (leaving the thread open for more comments). And if I find out what's wrong I will answer but still let you have the correct answer. :)